# is Ù the same as omega as the unit of resistance?

Tags: electrical-resistance, units

I was making an exercise about DC motors and the resistance was given in Ù. Is this the same unit as Ω? Or is there a relation between these two units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very probably seeing a misprint due to text encoding errors

As an example of the misprints that can be introduced by encoding errors, consider the following:

In code page 437, character 234 is the Ohm symbol / Greek omega.

In code page 850, character 234 is capital U with circumflex.

[image]

There are a great many encodings. I have not found a specific pair of encodings that would cause a Ω (or something related, such as ρ) to appear as Ù (U with grave accent).

Comment: 235 looks like delta, not rho

Comment: Note that OP encountered a Ù (capital U grave accent) not a Û (capital U circumflex). But I believe the general idea of "encoding error" is correct.

Comment: @David, Floris: Thanks, I have adjusted my answer accordingly.